# Three.js how to get PointCloud vertices with global positions

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-clouds

I have a PointCloud in my scene. The PointCloud is translated and rotated.

Now I want to export all pointCloud vertices with gloabalWorld positions.

```
PointCloud.geometry.__vertexArray
```

returns all vertices at the local positions. In which way I can get the global positions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do someting like this for meshes, I think it works for point clouds, too.

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
for ( var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++ ) {
    var vertex = vertices[ i ].clone();
    vertex.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
    // do something with the transformed vertex
}
```